# Sync Planner APP Task with External Database

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, microsoft-planner

I am going to add the Planner App in the MS Teams Channel using Graph API. 
I will add Tasks to it as well using Graph API.
Now I want that whenever status is getting changed in the planner app for the tasks then I can update the status in my database to. means I want to sync the tasks table in my database with the Planner app.

How it is possible?

Comment: Have you considered Microsoft Flow or logic apps to export Microsoft Planner tasks to a SQL database? See https://asia.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/1879528b45314f74bed7639405a8c1be/export-microsoft-planner-tasks-to-a-sql-database/. But there is no trigger for updating of status. Only a triger for "When a task is completed".

Comment: Any updates? Is my information useful?

Comment: @AllenWu   The tasks that i created to planer exists in my database too. So I want that whenever there is some activity in planner tab then that can be recorded in my database too. based on your solution it will insert all tasks to database but will not able to deal with activities.

Answer (score 0):

To deliver change notifications to clients, MS Graph API uses a webhook mechanism. Client apps can configure urls to receive notifications and use these notifications to update states. Please see documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks. This is not yet available for Planner tasks, would you kindly raise a feature request here: https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests